# Do you recognize these polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, mathematica

Consider the integral

$$f_k (x) := \int_{- \infty}^{+  \infty} dt \, t^k \, e^{-t^2 + x t} \, , \quad k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

According to Mathematica:

$$f_k(x) = \frac{1 -(-1)^k}{2} \, x \,  \Gamma \left( 1+ \frac{k}{2} \right) \, \, _1 F_1 \left( 1+ \frac{k}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{x^2}{4} \right) \\
 \qquad \qquad +  \frac{1 +(-1)^k}{2}  \,  \Gamma \left(  \frac{1+k}{2} \right) \, \, _1 F_1 \left( \frac{1+k}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{x^2}{4} \right) ,$$

in terms of the gamma function $\Gamma(x)$ and the hypergeometric function $_1F_1(x,y,z)$. At least for the first few terms, this can be written as

$$f_k(x) = \sqrt{\pi} \, e^{x^2/4} \, p_k(x/2) ,$$

where $p_k(x)$ are the polynomials

$$p_0(x) = 1\\
p_1(x) =  x \\
p_2(x) = x^2 + \frac{1}{2} \\
p_3(x) = x^3 + \frac{3}{2} x \\
p_4(x) = x^4 + 3x^2 + \frac{3}{4}\\
p_5(x) = x^5 + 5x^3 + \frac{15}{4}x\\
...$$

Are these known polynomials? Are they orthogonal wrt some weight function?

Comment: These are essentially [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

Comment: Right, you mean the second formula here: https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/HermiteH/07/ShowAll.html ?

Comment: I mean $p_k(x) = H_k(ix)/(2i)^k.$

Comment: @Somos maybe you want to take a look at my new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491392/gaussian-integral-of-hermite-polynomials